# how can i list items in one field MySQL?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i have a table filled with models,the models start year and end year and productid's that are assigned to it

```
ModelNo | StartYear | EndYear | ProductID |  
0       | 1997      | 2000    | 511777    |  
1       | 1998      | 1998    | 511789    |
```

what i'd like is an sql result as follows:

```
ProductID | Profile  
511777    | 0-1997,0-1998,0-1999,0-2000  
511789    | 1-1998
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how i could achieve this.

DPERROTT

Comment: Why would you need that as a MySQL result. It is possible but way to overloaded doing it in MySQL. I would recommend doing it in a programming language after querying the data.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to join onto an auxiliary [numbers table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) (containing sequential integers) to bring the missing numbers in the range in. i.e. something like

```
... FROM Models m
JOIN Numbers n ON n.number >= m.StartYear AND n.number <= m.EndYear
```

Then use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to get `0-1997`

and [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get `0-1997,0-1998,0-1999,0-2000`